# Как отключить мобильную передачу данных?

Tags: android, java

Необходимо отключить мобильную передачу данных программным путем. Сам ползунок находиться в меню Настройка - Передача данных - Мобильная передача данных. Пробовал выключить и включить Wi-Fi, все просто:

```
wifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(service);

if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()){
        if (wifi.getWifiState() != WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING)                 
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
                }
                else{
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
                }
```

а вот с этим возникли проблемы.

Comment: Опять мне что ли отвечать?!

Comment: уже нет :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
void turnData(boolean ON) throws Exception
        {

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT  == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
            {

                Log.i("version:", "Found Froyo");
                try{
                    Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
                    Class telephonyManagerClass;
                    Object ITelephonyStub;
                    Class ITelephonyClass;
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
                    Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                    getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
                    ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
                    ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

                    if (ON) {
                        dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity");

                    } else {
                        dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
                    }
                    dataConnSwitchmethod.setAccessible(true);
                    dataConnSwitchmethod.invoke(ITelephonyStub);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error:",e.toString());
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("version:", "Found Gingerbread+");
                final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
                final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
                iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
                final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
                final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
                final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
                setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
                setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Угу, вижу копипаст со стэка... Ну, в любом случае это ответ.